# Remove $routeParams from URL without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am using ngRoute in my angular application and using `$routeParams` to send an `indicator` param from my `/edit` route to my `/list` route.

Here is my `$routeProvider` configuration.

```
$routeProvider.when('/edit', {
    controller: 'editController',
    templateUrl: 'templates/editForm.html'
}).when('/list', {
    controller: 'listController',
    templateUrl: 'templates/list.html'
}).when('/list/:indicator', {
    controller: 'listController',
    templateUrl: 'templates/list.html'
}).when('/', {redirectTo: '/listContacts'});
```

When someone clicks save on my edit page, I redirect back to the list page with an indicator that tells whether it was successful or not.

If successful:

```
$window.location.href = "#/list/success";
```

If not successful:

```
$window.location.href = "#/list/error";
```

This redirects to my list page properly and displays a success or error message depending on the indicator. This is how I detect the indicator and display the messages in my `listController`.

```
var indicator = $routeParams.indicator;
if (indicator) {
    if (indicator == 'success') {
        //show success message
    } else if (indicator == 'error') {
        //show error message
    }
}
```

Now, after I check the indicator route parameter, **I would like to remove the route parameter from the URL displayed in the browser, without reloading the page**.

If I modify the `$window.location.href` to remove the indicator, the page will be reloaded.

I have seen many suggestions using `$location.search('key', null)`, but that won't work in this case because ngRoute's parameters are passed as part of the route, rather than in a key-value pair after a `?`.

I have also seen a suggestion to just set `$routeParams = null`, but that does not work for me either.

How can I change

> mysite.com/myapp/#/list/success

to

> mysite.com/myapp/#/list

in the displayed URL in the browser without reloading the page/route?

Comment: likely better off using a service to track your `indicator` and/or a `resolve`. Also don't see why you couldn't use a search param. Can change search without reload